# How can i pass information with each notification?

Tags: android, notifications

I send users a new notification for every new offer.
i would like to be able to pass the Offer ID through the notification to the receiving Activity so that i can show the user the offer requested.

how can this be achieved?

Thanks

Comment: `how can this be achieved?` I bet with some code!

Answer (score 0):

Put the "Offer ID" in an extra of the `Intent` you use to create the `PendingIntent` that you use with the `Notification`. Be sure to pass `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` to the `getActivity()` call on `PendingIntent`, so your extra is taken into account, replacing any previous extra on any previous edition of the `PendingIntent`.

Comment: Thanks. The point is each update will erase the previous one, and i want each notification to carry the offer ID. the user could have 5 Notifications at a time each with a different ID. so i think your solution will not solve the problem.

Comment: @Yvan: First, having "5 Notifications at a time" is a bad UX. Have one `Notification` that leads the user to an activity that shows all five offers. The user's status bar is not your private playground. Second, for the rare cases where an app legitimately needs more than one `Notification` that leads to the same activity, you need unique `PendingIntents`, typically via different values for the second parameter to `getActivity()`.